# Qt: Function has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake

I work on the CMake-based Qt project in MS Visual Studio. When I try to evaluate any method of a Qt object, I receive the error:

```
Function <blablabla> has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.
```

[Image: QuickWatch evaluation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9pRZ.png)

I build in the DEBUG mode; I see the compiler invoked with no optimizations:

```
cl.exe ... /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
```

Also, I checked the PDBs are loaded:

[Image: VS Modules Window with PDBs loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRA5f.png)

But nothing of this helps: all the objects evaluated well, but Qt's - are not.

Is there anything that will make the Visual Studio evaluate Qt objects' properties?

Comment: You linked the example of the `QString::isEmpty()` method. Do you get the same error if you actually use the method in the code? The compiler can not optimize it away in this case and so you could rule that out as the source of the problem.

Comment: In the code, everything works quite well. If add `qDebug() << fileName.isEmpty()`, I see `true` or `false` in logs.

Comment: OK, and if you add `qDebug() << fileName.isEmpty()` can you then evaluate the property in Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope. The thing is the Visual Studio does not evaluate any Qt method. Regardless of its usage in the code.

Comment: OK, so it is not the compiler optimizing stuff away, it is Visual Studio being unable to access certain methods. Can Visual Studio evaluate a method you wrote yourself in a derived class? How about an overwritten method?

Comment: Yes, it can. It also can evaluate any of the standard library objects/methods. Qt objects are the only ones causing the issue.